# Opencv Omnidirectional Calibration Rectification

Tags: python, c++, opencv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I have a wide angle lens (>160 degrees). I have tried both the Pinhole and Fisheye models and they seem to provide clear rectified images with a little FOV sacrifice. So I decided to give a try with the Omnidirectional Model.

With the Omnidirectional model:

```
double rms = cv::omnidir::stereoCalibrate(Omni_L.RealP, Omni_L.ImageP, Omni_R.ImageP, Omni_L.img.size(), Omni_R.img.size(), K1, xi1, D1, K2, xi2, D2, rvec, tvec, rvecsL, tvecsL, flags, critia);
std::cout << "RMS : " << rms << std::endl;
```

I Get the following results after the Stereo-calibration

```
RMS : 0.527522

 Camera_Matrix1 :
 [773.9380049495828, 0, 394.6697338356358;
 0, 776.2094223216956, 382.016762545214;
 0, 0, 1]

 Xi-1 :[1.804945374650817]

 Distortion Parameters1:
 [0, 0, -0.009983732008104793, -0.004530718062523464]

 Camera_Matrix2:
 [783.1807043871861, 0, 393.2120687911561;
 0, 784.4790955477508, 386.7954078861521;
 0, 0, 1]

 Xi-2 :[1.837909340970556]

 Distortion Parameters2:
 [0, 0, -0.009779422171305124, -0.003723193186299092]

 rvec :[-0.003821627764900316;
 0.005567569400892289;
 0.001491183114878044]

 tvec:[-63.09243360480385;
 0.1195353275271446;
 0.9082801155496641]

 R: 
 [1, 0, 0;
 0, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 1]

 P: 
 [773.9380049495828, 0, 394.6697338356358;
 0, 776.2094223216956, 382.016762545214;
 0, 0, 1]
```

Then I do undistortion:

```
    cv::Mat R = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat Mapx, Mapy;
    cv::Mat P(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
    P = K1;
    
    cv::Mat orid = cv::imread("Left\\1.jpg");
    std::cout << orid.size();
    std::cout << "R : "<<R<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "P : " << P << std::endl;
    cv::Size s= orid.size();
    try {
        cv::omnidir::initUndistortRectifyMap(K1, D1, xi1, R, P, s, CV_32FC1, Mapx, Mapy, cv::omnidir::RECTIFY_PERSPECTIVE);// Knew, new_size);
        cv::remap(orid, DC, Mapx, Mapy, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.msg << std::endl; // output exception message
    }
    std::string Save_Original = "Distorted_Original" + std::to_string(10) + EXT;
    cv::imwrite(Save_Original, orid);
    std::string Save_Corrected = "Distorted_Corrected" + std::to_string(10) + EXT;
    cv::imwrite(Save_Corrected, DC);
```

**Question 1:**

Why the Radial distortion is zero?

**Question 2:**

The output of the undistortion image with rectification drastically reduces the FOV. Is there something wrong in my code?

***Original Image:***
[image: Original Image]
***Distortion Corrected Image:***
[image: Distortion Corrected]

**Question 3:**

What does the P and R do in the cv::omnidir::initUndistortRectifyMap() function?

**Question 4:**

Need Ideas on how to get good rectified images with more FoV with omnidirectional calibration?

---

**Post Trials:**

1. suggested by @sushi(commented below) to try RECTIFY_CYLINDRICAL for the same image and below is the result:

   `cv::omnidir::RECTIFY_CYLINDRICAL` -> Results are worse

[image: cv::omnidir::RECTIFY_CYLINDRICAL]

Comment: Do you have a single camera or a pair of cameras?

Comment: @Sushi I have stereo pair of cameras. But I have just provided single camera's distortion correction image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I recommend you to read this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d12/tutorial_omnidir_calib_main.html
Answering your questions:

1. Distortion coefficients depend on the distortion model that you choose.
2. Look at the tutorial (image rectification part), if you want to preserve all fov you have to change the flag to RECTIFY_CYLINDRICAL
3. P is "new" camera matrix for image after rectification, R is rotation transform between the original and object space. You can skip both of these parameters if you undistort your images using cv::omnidir::undistortImage. Look in the tutorial about recommended values for *knew*.
4. Look at the answer in point 2.

This is the result of my approach using RECTIFY_PERSPECTIVE, I don't know why RECTIFY_CYLINDRICAL does not work in this case:[image: This is the result of my approach]
To achieve it simply undistort your image like this:

```
cv::Size s = orid.size();
cv::Mat Knew = cv::Mat(cv::Matx33f(s.width / 4, 0, s.width / 2,
        0, s.height / 4, s.width / 2,
        0, 0, 1));
cv::MAt undistorted;
cv::omnidir::undistortImage(orid, undistorted, K1, D1, xi1, cv::omnidir::RECTIFY_PERSPECTIVE, Knew, orid.size());
```

Comment: I have edited the above post by also including the result of RECTIFY_CYLINDRICAL. Seems the Results are getting worse in this flag

Comment: How did you set the remaining parameters in the function? Especially how did you set the values in Knew matrix?

Comment: cv::omnidir::undistortImage() needs "knew" but when I am using  cv::omnidir::initUndistortRectifyMap(), do I need to give knew matrix?

Comment: No, you don't need the knew matrix if you undistort this way. Check my updated answer.